# Is there a way to pan, and or change the zoom of the camera?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I like Super mario 64, and it's good camera controls, but can I pan/zoom in dark souls 2 too? Sometimes, I want to pan the camera away from a brutal grab/repost happening on me. Or zoom out if I want to be able to see more at once.

All I know I can do is rotate it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no functionality in the game to change the zoom or view of the camera. It is set at a fixed length, that is centered on the player.